# Please add the existence of the Meta tag to What is Meta

Tags: support, meta

On our Help Center Page [What is Meta](https://stackapps.com/help/whats-meta) the following sentence is used:

> Feel free to ask questions about Stack Apps on Stack Apps, tagging them with the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [support](/questions/tagged/support) tags.

Can we somehow add that tagging with [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) is also convenient. I'm not an English grammar wonder so instead of me doing horrible things I'll accept suggestions for improved phrasing as answer.

To set expectations right: Moderators can't edit that page. I checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder about this English grammar:

> Feel free to ask questions about Stack Apps *on* Stack Apps directly, tagging them with the [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) tag, as well as either a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag.

I'm not above doing horrible things.